# How to define the charset of files preloaded by the link HTTP header?

Tags: google-chrome, utf-8, character-encoding, http-headers, preload

Unlike Firefox, Chrome 67 assumes utf-8 for files preloaded by the link HTTP header.

What is the syntax for hinting the correct charset?

I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
link: <example.js>; rel=preload; as=script; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why do you need this? The charset parameter should appear on the `Content-Type` header for the script you're preloading.

Comment: Also, you _really_ should just convert to UTF-8 if you can. Using ISO-8859-1 is a pretty bad idea these days.

Comment: As a workaround, I set the charset in the Content-Type Response header of example.js, which resolved the problem for this file. But the issue persists in Chrome, since we will have to do this for every preloaded static file.